# _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(PuserData), Debug Assertion Failed Visual C++ (MPI)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mpi

I am using MPI_Reduce and MPI_Scatter function to scatter an array of integers in "N" processors and printing the partial and accumulate sum of the array. I am using Microsoft MPI (MSMPI) on visual studio 2010. but each time at execution it gives an exception " _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(PuserData)" along the title "Debug Assertion Failed" The code is as under

```
enter code here
#include <mpi.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size;
    int rank;
    int partialsum=0;
    int root =0;
    int accum=0;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);


    int *globaldata = NULL;
    int *localdata = new int(4);

    if (rank == root) {
      globaldata = new int(size*4);
        for (int i=0; i<(size*4); i++)
        globaldata[i] =  2*i+1;

        cout<<"Processor"<<rank<<" has global data: ";
        for (int i=0; i<(size*4); i++)
         cout<<globaldata[i]<<" ";
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    MPI_Scatter(globaldata, 4, MPI_INT, localdata, 4, MPI_INT, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    cout<<"Processor "<<rank<<"has local data";
    for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
        cout<<" "<<localdata[i];
    cout<<endl;
    for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
      partialsum += localdata[k];

    cout<<"Processor "<<rank<<" Partial Sum = "<<partialsum<<"\n";

    MPI_Reduce(&partialsum,&accum,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM, root,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == 0) {
      cout<<"Processor "<<rank<<" Accumulated Sum = "<<accum;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is very simple and lies here:

```
globaldata = new int(size*4);
```

The syntax to allocate dynamic arrays with the `new` operator is `new type[size]`:

```
globaldata = new int[size*4];
```

In your case a space for a single `int` is allocated and set to `size*4` instead and the initialisation code that immediately follows the allocation of memory at the root overwrites past the end of the allocated memory, thus destroying the heap structure.